# Indexing subcategories vs finding them dynamically (performance)

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance

I'm building a web-based store application, and I have to deal with many nested subcategories within each other. The point is, I have no idea whether my script will handle thousands (the new system will replace the old one, so I know what traffic I have to expect) - at the present day, respond lag from the local server is 1-2 seconds more than other pages with added about 30 products in different categories.

My code is the following:

```
    BazaArkadiaDataContext db = new BazaArkadiaDataContext();
    List<A_Kategorie> Podkategorie = new List<A_Kategorie>();

    public int IdKat { get; set; }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            List<A_Produkty> Produkty = new List<A_Produkty>(); //list of all products within the category and remaining subcategories

            if (Page.RouteData.Values["IdKategorii"] != null)
            {
                string tmpkat = Page.RouteData.Values["IdKategorii"].ToString();
                int index = tmpkat.IndexOf("-");
                if (index > 0)
                    tmpkat = tmpkat.Substring(0, index);
                IdKat = db.A_Kategories.Where(k => k.ID == Convert.ToInt32(tmpkat)).Select(k => k.IDAllegro).FirstOrDefault();
            }
            else
                return;

            PobierzPodkategorie(IdKat);

            foreach (var item in Podkategorie)
            {
                var x = db.A_Produkties.Where(k => k.IDKategorii == item.ID);
                foreach (var itemm in x)
                {
                    Produkty.Add(itemm);
                }
            }

            //data binding here
        }
    }

    List<A_Kategorie> PobierzPodkategorie(int IdKat, List<A_Kategorie> kat = null)
    {
        List<A_Kategorie> Kategorie = new List<A_Kategorie>();
        if (kat != null)
            Kategorie.Concat(kat);

        Kategorie = db.A_Kategories.Where(k => k.KatNadrzedna == IdKat).ToList();

        if (Kategorie.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in Kategorie)
            {
                PobierzPodkategorie(item.IDAllegro, Kategorie);
                Podkategorie.Add(item);
            }
        }
        return Kategorie;
    }
```

**TMC;DR***

My function `PobierzPodkategorie` recursively seeks through subcategories (subcategory got `KatNadrzedna` column for its parent category, which is placed in `IDAllegro`), selects all the products with the subcategory ID and adds it to the `Produkty` list. The database structure is pretty wicked, as the category list is downloaded from another shop service server and it needed to get our own ID column in case the foreign server would change the structure.

There are more than 30 000 entries in the category list, some of them will have 5 or more parents, and the website will show only main categories and subcategories ("lower" subcategories are needed by external shop connected with SOAP).

**My question is**

Will adding index table to the database (Category `123` is parent for `1234`, `12738`...) will improve the performance, or is it just waste of time? (The index should be updated when version of API changes and I have no idea how often would it be) Or is there other way to do it?

I'm asking because changing the script will not be possible in production, and I don't know how the db engine handles lots of requests - I'd really appreciate any help with this.

The database is MSSQL

---

*Too much code; didn't read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big efficiency gain you can get is to load all subproducts in a single query.  The time saved by reducing network trips can be huge.  If `1` is a root category and `12` a child category, you can query all root categories and their children like:

```
select  *
from    Categories
where   len(Category) <= 2
```

An index on Category would not help with the above query.  But it's good practice to have a primary key on any table.  So I'd make Category the primary key.  A primary key is unique, preventing duplicates, and it is indexed automatically.

Moving away from RBAR (row by agonizing row) has more effect than proper tuning of the database.  So I'd tackle that first.

Comment: I know a little SQL and I didn't know that it was possible - thank you for this. Will it be possible (and/or worth) to put such function into `database methods` to use it later? And yes, I have primary key with `AUTO_INCREMENT` in every table, sometimes I'm even angry why does my database can't create it automatically when creating tables ;)

Answer (score 1):

You definitely should move the recursion into database. It can be done using `WITH` statement and [Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Then create a view or stored procedure and map it to you application.

With that you should be able to reduce SQL queries to two (or even one).

Comment: Thanks for the response - I think I need to finally learn SQL just to know what it is possible to do there...